# See sender's email-address in Google Inbox for iOS

Tags: ios, gmail, google

How do I see a sender's email in Google's email-app Inbox for iOS?

I cannot click the displayed name or the photo, either while reading the email or when answering it. It just shows, in this case, an unknown first name of someone.

Answer (score 3):

The extended headers can be viewed by tapping the "to me" that in small, gray text shown under the sender's name. The "tap target" (area where you can effectively tap to initiate the action) is very small.

The email address is then visible next to the sender's name.